# How to reconstruct the signal after decomposition

Tags: signal-processing, decomposition

[C,L] = wavedec(sig_new,6,waveletFunction);
After decomposing the EEG signal I reconstructed signal by compressing all decomposed sub-signals. After getting reconstructed signal, I compare reconstructed signal with original signal by using "mean square error" to find the best waveletFunction

1. How to reconstruct the signal.  For decomposition I used:

   [C,L] = wavedec(sig_new, 6, waveletFunction);
   For reconstruction I used:

   X = waverec(C,L,waveletFunction);

Please tell me the reconstruction procedure is correct or not.
I think it is not the correct way. Because I didn't get any difference between the reconstructed signal and original signal. Please help me.

```
  waveletFunction = 'db1';
  [C,L] = wavedec(sig_new,8,waveletFunction);
  cD1 = detcoef(C,L,1);
  cD2 = detcoef(C,L,2);
  cD3 = detcoef(C,L,3);
  cD4 = detcoef(C,L,4);
  cD5 = detcoef(C,L,5); %GAMA
  cD6 = detcoef(C,L,6); %BETA
  cD7 = detcoef(C,L,7); %ALPHA
  cD8 = detcoef(C,L,8); %THETA
  cA8 = appcoef(C,L,waveletFunction,8); %DELTA



(or)

D1 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,1);    
D2 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,2);
D3 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,3);
D4 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,4);
D5 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,5); %GAMMA
D6 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,6); %BETA
D7 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,7); %ALPHA
D8 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,8); %THETA
A8 = wrcoef('a',C,L,waveletFunction,8); %DELTA
```

Among above two decompositions which one is correct? What is the difference between them?
Please help me for completing my research work.